# Read xml attribute with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS>
        <DATETIME type="valid_start_date">
          <DATE>2015-07-01</DATE>
        </DATETIME>
        <DATETIME type="valid_end_date">
          <DATE></DATE>
        </DATETIME>
</ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS>
```

How can i get value in the  Element?

I tried this one

```
   var productQuery = (from p in xmlDocument.Descendants("ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS")
                        select new
                        {

                            articleDatetime = p.Element("DATETIME")
                                               .Attribute("valid_start_date")
                                               .Value

                        });
```

when i try to use articleDatetime , i got an exception.
need help to me

Comment: What exactly exception you're getting?

Comment: You don't have an attribute that is named "valid_start_date". You have an attribute named "type". What are you trying to do?

Comment: @YacoubMassad thank you for your attention and you really right that.
I was using wrong attribute name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're trying to get value of `DATE` element under `DATETIME` having atribute `type="valid_start_date"`.

It can be done by various ways, here is one of them:

```
var dates = xmlDocument
     .XPathSelectElements("ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS/DATETIME[@type='valid_start_date']/DATE")
     .Select(e => e.Value)
     .ToList();
```

Notice here most of the job is done with `XPathSelectElements` method and appropriate xpath expression.

The same result can be achieved also without using xpath selection, only by a couple of linq calls like:

```
var xmlDocument = doc.Descendants("ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS")
                     .Descendants("DATETIME")
                     .Where(e => e.Attribute("type")?.Value == "valid_start_date")
                     .Descendants("DATE")
                     .Select(e => e.Value)
                     .ToList();
```

But it looks less readable (at least from my point of view).